# Rails delayed_jobs asking for "sender/from" when sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, asynchronous, delayed-job

I am trying to set up asynchronous email sending. I am using delayed_job. Withoud delayed_job everything works without any error. But when I add:

```
handle_asynchronously :mail_sending_method
```

I get the following error:

```
A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message
```

I use ActionMailer for sending mails, specifically like this:

```
mail(:to => user.email, :from => "notifications@example.com", :subject => "Blah")
```

Here is the method:

```
def phrase_email(user, tweet, keyword, phrase)
    @user = user
    @tweet = tweet
    @keyword = keyword
    @phrase = phrase
    mail(:to => user.email, :from => "notifications@example.com", :subject => "Weekapp     Phrase Notification")
end
```

Comment: could you post `mail_sending_method` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delayed Job works differently with Rails 3 `Mailers`.

```
class YourMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def phrase_email(user, tweet, keyword, phrase)
    @user = user
    @tweet = tweet
    @keyword = keyword
    @phrase = phrase
    mail(:to => user.email, :from => "notifications@example.com", :subject => "Weekapp    Phrase Notification")
  end
end
```

So, use `delay` or `deliver` as below while calling to your mailer method.

```
 YourMailer.delay.phrase_email(user, tweet, keyword, phrase) #With delay

 YourMailer.phrase_email(user, tweet, keyword, phrase).deliver  #Without delay
```

And remove `handle_asynchronously` from your YourMailer.

It is clearly mentioned in documentation [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). You can't use `handle_asynchronously` with mailers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and I didn't get any error message... But I am not getting any emails either... I'll check it later one more time...

Comment: Did you check delayed job from console and delayed job log ?? I think it is working correct. To get mail to your inbox in development mode you need to configure something. So I use `mailtrap` to check mail thing is working correctly or not. See this https://github.com/mmower/mailtrap

Comment: Hi again. I am back to this problem. So I have figured out that in table delayed jobs my emails are being stored but eventually they are not sent. How can I make it send emails to real addresses?

Comment: Yup, that's it... I haven't run that daemon :D Thanks a lot for your help!